# How to match values in arrays and match result against key/val pair

Tags: groovy

I'm using Groovy.

I've got two sets of data. The first is an array of site codes and the second is a key/val map of some JSON data.

I need to loop through the list of site codes and match them to key in the map. Once it finds a match it needs to return the corresponding map val.

The map array looks like this:

```
list = ["WSM-3572", "WSM-0301","WSM-10153"]
```

A keypair looks like this:

```
{id=3dd9794a-d148-4f74-a297-cefe22d05cfd, name=Nedbank Mall of Africa(WSM-3572)},{id=8fb57fda-8bdf-4aef-8d50-f3bf8d2235e1, name=Caffe Rossini (WSM-3432)}, 
{id=bd12b3ef-b72f-4211-8987-2e0c6f1f688d, name=Steers Welkom (WSM-4502)},
```

So in the above case we should run through the list and when it gets to `WSM-3572` it should find it and match the site code in the name: `Nedbank Mall of Africa(WSM-3572)` and then return `id=3dd9794a-d148-4f74-a297-cefe22d05cfd`.

I hope this all makes sense and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've loaded your json into a map with JsonSlurper, something like

```
list.each { code ->
    println "$code = " + json.find { it ->
        it.name.contains "($it)"
    }?.id
}
```

Should do it.

Not at a computer, but that should be close

Comment: Great! Thank you.